# How to link multiple guest events to one user in Mixpanel using HTTP API?

Tags: mixpanel

I can't seem to understand how to link multiple guests events with the same user in mixpanel once they log-in with the same credential. like one user using different browsers.

If a guest (with distinct id: uuid1) logs in with a user email abc@gmail.com I want to update Mixpanel user's distinct id to abc@gmail.com. if that user uses a 2nd browser (with distinct id: uuid2) and then logs in with the same email, I want to connect those events with the corresponding user's distinct id (abc@gmail.com).

There should be only one user profile in Mixpanel and all those guests events should link to that user. I prefer to do it client side using HTTP API (I can't use JS SDK) but if it's not possible I could think about a server approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Events can be sent at any time but `identity` method should be called on the user sign-up or login event. upon calling identity method, mixpanel will then link the previous anonymous id to the main user id. There can be up to 500 anon id linked to one user id.